# Ao extender models do passport setTable não funciona

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Extendi os 5 models do passport:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Extendi pois tenho que adicionar o shema ao nome das tabelas e para isso tenho usado esta função no construtor dos meus outros models:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setTableName('financial_profile');
}
```

E extendido nos models o `GSModel`:

```
class GSModel extends Model
{
    protected $schema;

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->schema = config('database.schema');
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('notExcluded', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('is_excluded', false)->orWhereNull('is_excluded');
        });
    }

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function setTableName($table) {
        $this->setTable($this->schema.'.'.$table);
    }
}
```

Nos models extendidos do passport tentei fazer assim como no exemplo:

```
class OauthAccessTokens extends Token
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $schema = config('database.schema');

        $this->setTable($schema.'.oauth_access_tokens');
    }
}
```

E ele até funciona corretamente, por exemplo, ao dar o `php artisan migrate` os arquivos são criados nos locais corretos, dentro do schema.

E ao rodar o `php artisan passport::install` os clients os clients são gerados na tabela corretamente.

Porém, quando gero os tokens este não armazena o `access token`, `refresh token` nem o `remember token`.

Porem como a classe `Token`, por exemplo, extende a classe Model, a mesma que o GSModel extende, entendo que deveria funcionar da mesma forma.

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Passport;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Token extends Model
```

Agora se simplesmente altero os models para o seguinte formato, tudo passa a funcionar corretamente.

```
class OauthAccessTokens extends Token
{
    protected $table = 'gs_schema.oauth_access_tokens';
}
```

Preciso que o schema seja informado no `.env`, e da forma anterior estava funcionando corretamente até então, alguma sujestão de como posso fazer isso?

Hoje tenho no `config/database.php` o código:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Schema Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

'schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA', ''),
```

E no meu `.env`:

```
DB_SCHEMA=gs_schema
```

Comment: A classe OauthAccessTokens  não tem que estender a classe GSModel ao invés de Token? Eu não trabalhei com o Passport ainda, mas se ele testa se a classe é do tipo Token, então você precisa fazer a classe GSModel estender de Token e OauthAccessTokens estender de GSModel